# Holomorphic extension theorem over a compact convex subset

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I've just come across an exercise  in complex analysis that: Let $U\subset \mathbb C^n$, $n>1$ be a domain and $K\subset\subset U$ be a compact geometrically convex subset. If $f\in \mathcal O(U\setminus K)$ then prove that $f$ extends to be holomorphic in $U$.

Hint: Find a nice point on $\partial K$ and try extending a little bit. Then make sure your extension is single-valued.

I would like to see a proof of this using this hint.. Thanks

Comment: Other hint: use max modulo principle

Comment: is convexity important in your hint?

Comment: hmm yes, because the border of the open set (U-K) must be homotopic to a interior point

Comment: @vvnitram Can you give another hint? Or outline the argument?